# This is the command to find number of lines of code that i have written?

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-kernel

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec cat {} \; | sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d;/^\s*\/\//d' | wc -l
```

Can anyone explain the meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Explanation**:

`find . -type f -name '*.c'` - find all files in current directory recursively with any symbols in name and `.c` extention. See `man find`

`-exec cat {} \;` - get content of files found on previous step. See -exec construction: `-exec command {} +`

`sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d;/^\s*///d'` - remove several types of "comments" (or something similar). This part contain 3 section devided with `;`. Where:

1. `/^\s*#/d` - start of line (`^`), 0, 1 or more spaces (`\s*`) and `#` symbol. `//d` - delete matched string;
2. `/^\s*$/d` - empty lines. The same of the previous part but with `$` symbol which mean end of line
3. `/^\s*\/\//d` - matches lines with two slashes (`\/\/`, `\` - backslash to quote the slash) and 0,1 or more spaces in front of them

`wc -l` - counting the number of lines of code

Comment: `#` doesn't start a comment in `c` files. Actually, the classical `c` comments `/* like this */` are not removed. I never understood why people count lines of code anyhow ...

Comment: let it remain a secret))

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -type f -name '*.c'
```

find any file that ends with .c

```
-exec cat {} \;
```

run `cat` command to print the file (which is actually nonsense: the filename could be passed as an argument directly to `sed` instead of piping it)

```
| sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d;/^\s*\/\//d'
```

remove any preprocessor directives, empty lines and comments from the file (you can view your file without comments by removing the `| wc -l` part from the command)

```
| wc -l
```

Count the total number of lines displayed after filtering out the comments.

Comment: It does not remove comments.

Comment: /^\s*\/\//d does remove the single line comments which start like this // Doesnt work on multiline comments though

Comment: Yes, it does remove any line that has (only) a C99 comment, but leaves classic C comments in place.

Answer (score 0):

Explain the meaning? Okay. I think it means that someone loves piping stdout from command to command.

I think the whole thing could be replaced by a simple

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec grep -cv -e '^\s*#' -e '^\s*$' -e '^\s*//' {} \;
```